# shortcut for commands

Tags: linux

I use following commands very often, and they're too long.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc start
sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc stop
```

how can I create a shortcut command for them? something like `sudo kerio start` or `sudo kerio stop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file, then add an *alias*:

```
alias kstart='sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc start'
alias kstop='sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc stop'
```

Then :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now `kstart` and `kstop` are accessible.

### Note :

most of linux distros now use systemd, so it would be :

```
sudo systemctl start kerio-kvc
```